# I told you that

Tags: commas

I was writing a sentence to send to a friend.
The sentence is: I told you that after you get all A's in your classes, I would get you a unicorn.

Should there be a comma after "that"? Also, I shouldn't have to quote myself, do I? 
I feel like the correct way should be: I told you that, "After you get all A's in your classes, I would get you a unicorn." So, here you go.

I was stumped because it seems as if I'm saying this: I told you that―*but only after you've done this*―I would get you that thing.

And so, without the requirement, "I told you that I would get you that thing."

It's not a *I-told-you-so* type of thing; it's suppose to be said as if I wanted them to remember what I told them awhile ago. That's what I had in mind, anyways.

I refrained from using quotations in the message, since it seems awkward to quote myself, in my opinion. What I'm sending is a stuffed animal with a gift message attached to it. This is probably quite simple and I'm just perplexing it. Curious and need help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The easiest way to solve your problem is to remove the _that_ and rearrange the sentence; I'd also shift the second _get_ to past tense: ***I told you I would get you a unicorn after you got all A's in your classes.***

Comment: Thank you―that's a lot smoother. I changed it to "I said I would get you a unicorn after you got all A's in your classes."